# I am trying to create a .bat script to edit a bunch of xml files. I am encounterring a lot of errors

Tags: xml, batch-file, automation, batch-processing

What I want is:
if XML File contains CASES.PRIORITY and/or CASES.SUBJECT remove both of them and if file contains Category__c and Sub_Category__c then end. Else if they don't exist, add them below Created_By_for_list_view__c if this field doesn't exist add below CASES.STATUS and even if this doesn't exist, just add inside

Don't know where the bug is, but the content is getting duplicated inside the xml file instead of the result I wanted.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search1=<columns>CASES.PRIORITY</columns>"
set "search2=<columns>CASES.SUBJECT</columns>"
set "search3=<columns>Category__c</columns>"
set "search4=<columns>Sub_Category__c</columns>"
set "search5=<columns>Created_By_for_list_view__c</columns>"
set "search6=<columns>CASES.STATUS</columns>"

for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /s C:\Users\V-SPogula\Downloads\sand\*.xml') do (
  set "insertionPoint="
  set "line=1"
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "%%f"`) do (
    if "%%a"=="%search1%" echo.%%a>>"%%f.tmp"
    if "%%a"=="%search2%" echo.%%a>>"%%f.tmp"
    if not "%%a"=="%search3%" if not "%%a"=="%search4%" (
      if "%%a"=="%search5%" set "insertionPoint=after_%%line%"
      if "%%a"=="%search6%" set "insertionPoint=after_%%line%"
      echo.%%a>>"%%f.tmp"
    )
    if "%%a"=="%search3%" if not defined insertionPoint set "insertionPoint=inside_%%line%"
    if "%%a"=="%search4%" if not defined insertionPoint set "insertionPoint=inside_%%line%"
    set /a "line=line+1"
  )
  if not defined insertionPoint (
    set "line=1"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "%%f"`) do (
      echo.%%a>>"%%f.tmp"
      if "%%a"=="<ListView>" set "insertionPoint=inside_%%line%"
      set /a "line=line+1"
    )
  )
  if defined insertionPoint (
    set "line=1"
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`type "%%f"`) do (
      echo.%%a>>"%%f.tmp"
      set /a "line=line+1"
      if "!insertionPoint!"=="inside_%%line!" (
        echo.<columns>Category__c</columns>>"%%f.tmp"
        echo.<columns>Sub_Category__c</columns>>"%%f.tmp"
      )
      if "!insertionPoint:after_=!"=="%%line" (
        echo.<columns>Category__c</columns>>"%%f.tmp"
        echo.<columns>Sub_Category__c</columns>>"%%f.tmp"
      )
    )
  )
  move /y "%%f.tmp" "%%f" >nul
)
```

Comment: You didn't mention what any of the errors are or what question you have about them specifically.

Comment: Please show current and desired XML. Consider XSLT for any XML modifications run by PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
rem The following settings for the directories and filenames are names
rem that I use for testing and deliberately includes spaces to make sure
rem that the process works using such names. These will need to be changed to suit your situation.

SET "sourcedir=u:\your files"
SET "destdir=u:\your results"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q75061016.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

set "search1=<columns>CASES.PRIORITY</columns>"
set "search2=<columns>CASES.SUBJECT</columns>"
set "search3=<columns>Category__c</columns>"
set "search4=<columns>Sub_Category__c</columns>"
set "search5=<columns>Created_By_for_list_view__c</columns>"
set "search6=<columns>CASES.STATUS</columns>"

:: Examine source file

FOR /L %%b IN (1,1,6) DO SET "found%%b="

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF "!line:%search4%=!" neq "%%b" SET "found4=y"
 IF "!line:%search5%=!" neq "%%b" SET "found5=y"
 IF "!line:%search6%=!" neq "%%b" SET "found6=y"

)

IF DEFINED found3 IF DEFINED found4 ECHO found both strings&GOTO :eof

SET "inserthere="
(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%b IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%b"
 IF "!line:%search1%=!" == "%%b" IF "!line:%search2%=!" == "%%b" (
  IF DEFINED search1 (
   IF DEFINED found5 (
    IF "!line:%search5%=!" neq "%%b" SET "inserthere=y"
   ) ELSE IF DEFINED found6 IF "!line:%search6%=!" neq "%%b" SET "inserthere=y"
  )
  SETLOCAL disabledelayedexpansion
  ECHO %%b
  endlocal
  IF DEFINED inserthere FOR %%e IN ("%search1%" "%search2%") DO (
   ECHO %%~e
   SET "inserthere="
   SET "search1="
  )
 )
)
IF DEFINED search1 FOR %%e IN ("%search1%" "%search2%") DO ECHO %%~e
)>"%outfile%"

FC "%filename1%" "%outfile%"

GOTO :eof
```

This should do as you ask.

First see whether the critical strings exist in the file, setting `found?`.

Then process the file, skipping the lines containing the strings not wanted,
and inserting them when the appropriate line is found.

`search1` is set to *nothing* (ie. undefined) when an insertion has taken place, so if it survives the processing, then no insertion has occurred and do the insertion process.

It's not clear whether "them" refers to `search1/2` or `search3/4`. If `search3/4` is required, replace `search1/2` with `search3/4` in each of the `for..%%e` lines.